# First time owning a cat

Tags: cats, behavior, feeding, adoption, fear

This is the first time I have a cat in my life. She is almost 10 months. She came home yesterday and she was wandering around the house, which has a litter box, food, and water.

This morning, I found my cat hiding under the bed and she hasn't come out since then. She isn't drinking nor eating. She isn't even thinking about coming out.

How do I make this cat eat or drink? Would treats help it out?

Answer (score 8):

There are many things you can try to solve your problem. The easiest of which is as follows:

Find a small room in your house, where you go often, that has a door. Such as a bedroom. Take all the things your new kitten needs into that room, and close the door. Keep the cat in there, and let it slowly get used to just that part of your house. Once your cat seems comfortable there, slowly introduce it to other places in your house, and expand its territory. Treats may help with this. Make sure your cat is happy with her food and litter. If this behaviour continues, it is time to consult a vet.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Your cat is scared, obviously, and will come out when she gets used to her new home.

The first thing to do now is to get her some food. Take some wet food on a plate (you might add a couple of spoons of water to the food), push this under the bed, then walk away so she can eat alone.

If the cat stays under the bed for more than 2-3 days, it is time to make it come out. Reach your hand behind the cat and gently make the cat move out of her hiding place. When the cat is out, pet her for a short time before letting her go. And don't do so until 2-3 days have passed.

You can also make or get some small toys and try to get her to play with them to make your cat forget that she is scared for a moment while she is playing.

Your cat feels safe under the bed for now, but you have to make the cat feel safe in all the other places in your home too.

Your cat might have had an accident under the bed and this must be cleaned up.

The first couple of days in a new place can be stressful for a little cat, so you must try to comfort her as best you can.

Comment: I'd place the food and water not under the bed but just a bit away from it. Not far enough that there's a large gap, but just enough that the cat needs to get out from under the bed, realise nothing bad happens when doing so, and still provide a place to quickly retreat to.

Answer (score 1):

Is your cat really not eating and drinking, or are you not seeing him/her doing so?

My cat did much the same when he just arrived in my house (now several years ago).
For days I'd not see him, but his food and water were being consumed. He didn't eat or drink a lot, lost some weight, but he was eating and drinking a little, always making sure that he was alone in the room when doing so.

This lasted a few days, until he came out and approached me, wanting to be petted. 
I gave him some treats, scratched his ears for a few minutes, and he's been the best friend ever since.